# GROUP BY and ORDER BY not working together

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this select that displays users events based on date. But now results are displayed in good order but without todays events and I need them too. I am grouping it by users id:

```
SELECT 
a.id,
a.title,
a.name,
a.surname,
a.zip,
a.city,
a.address,
a.spec,
a.active,
b.start,
b.user,
b.status 
FROM user a 
INNER JOIN appointement b 
ON a.id=b.user WHERE a.spec='$spec' 
AND b.status='open' 
AND a.active='1' 
AND b.start>='$date' 
GROUP BY a.id 
ORDER BY b.start ASC
```

Date in database is in this format: 2014-07-31 08:15:00 just like `$date`
Can problem be in that date?

Comment: You are grouping by a.id . It will bring back one row per id. The details from your appointment table will be for any one of the matching appointments for that user.

Comment: @Kickstart ok, but I did order by date and it doesnt work. I dont see first date as result for every user

Comment: You should delete this question and ask another question, with sample data and desired results.  I suspect that you are trying to do something, and this simply isn't the right way to do it.  Plus, you are using a MySQL extension to group by with lots of columns in the `select` that are not in aggregation functions or the `group by`.  That is generally a bad idea.

Comment: The order by applies to the results of the query, not to choosing which of multiple rows from the query will be chosen to be output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a GROUP BY clause all the rows are put together based on ones that share the same value of the field in the GROUP BY clause. Other fields are designed to be from aggregate functions although MySQL does not enforce this by default.

With your query you are trying to get all the appointments for each user. But as you GROUP BY the id of the user it will narrow down the appointments to one single appoitnment for that user. Which appointment it chooses is not defined, and is subject to change.

If you wanted a single row per user with all the appointment details for that user you could use GROUP_CONCAT to put them all into one field.

```
SELECT 
    a.id,
    a.title,
    a.name,
    a.surname,
    a.zip,
    a.city,
    a.address,
    a.spec,
    a.active,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS('-', b.start, b.user, b.status))
FROM user a 
INNER JOIN appointement b 
ON a.id=b.user WHERE a.spec='$spec' 
AND b.status='open' 
AND a.active='1' 
AND b.start>='$date' 
GROUP BY a.id 
ORDER BY b.start ASC
```

If you just want the first relevant appointment per use then use a sub query to identify that, and join that to appointments to get the details

```
SELECT 
    a.id,
    a.title,
    a.name,
    a.surname,
    a.zip,
    a.city,
    a.address,
    a.spec,
    a.active,
    b.start,
    b.user,
    b.status 
FROM user a 
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT user, MIN(start) AS first_app
    FROM appointment
    WHERE status='open' 
    AND start>='$date' 
    GROUP BY user
) sub0
ON a.id = sub0.user
INNER JOIN appointement b 
ON a.id=b.user 
AND sub0.first_app = b.start
WHERE a.spec='$spec' 
AND b.status='open' 
AND a.active='1' 
AND b.start>='$date' 
ORDER BY b.start ASC
```

Comment: Thank you for effort but I am not getting any results with second select. No errors but no results also

Comment: Can you set up an sqlfiddle with the tables and a few lines of data to demonstrate what you want? Possible I have made a typo but I can't see it and with some test data I can hopefully spot it quickly.